# always prompt for default directory when opening interactive subshell

Tags: tramp, shell

When I invoke `C-u M-x shell` while visiting a local file or scratch buffer, emacs does not prompt me to enter the default directory for the shell.

But if I'm visiting a remote file or directory through tramp, then when invoking `C-u M-x shell`, emacs will ask me for the default directory.

How can I make `C-u M-x shell` ask for the default directory even when I'm visiting a local file or buffer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not foreseen in the code of `shell`. It asks for a default directory only in case the current default directory is remote. The comment says

`;; It must be possible to declare a local default-directory.`

If you want an option to be asked at every invocation of `shell`, you might write a wishlist report via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.